# Stack is blocking for widget buttons expanding

Tags: flutter

From [here](https://github.com/fireship-io/170-flutter-animated-radial-menu/blob/master/lib/main.dart) why is it, that when I put it in a Stack the buttons is no longer working - that is the surrounding buttons, the main center button is still working?

It is like the Stack is blocking for hits.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' show radians, Vector3;
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter',
        home: Scaffold(
            body: SizedBox.expand(child: Stack(children: [Positioned(
                top: 400,
                left: 150,
                child: RadialMenu())]))));
  }
}

class RadialMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => _RadialMenuState();
}

class _RadialMenuState extends State<RadialMenu> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 900), vsync: this);
    // ..addListener(() => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RadialAnimation(key: UniqueKey(), controller: controller);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


class RadialAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  RadialAnimation({ required Key key, required this.controller }) :

        translation = Tween<double>(
          begin: 0.0,
          end: 100.0,
        ).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(
              parent: controller,
              curve: Curves.elasticOut
          ),
        ),

        scale = Tween<double>(
          begin: 1.5,
          end: 0.0,
        ).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(
              parent: controller,
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn
          ),
        ),

        rotation = Tween<double>(
          begin: 0.0,
          end: 360.0,
        ).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(
            parent: controller,
            curve: Interval(
              0.0, 0.7,
              curve: Curves.decelerate,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        super(key: key);

  final AnimationController controller;
  final Animation<double> rotation;
  final Animation<double> translation;
  final Animation<double> scale;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: controller,
        builder: (context, widget) {
          return Transform.rotate(
              angle: radians(rotation.value),
              child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _buildButton(0, color: Colors.red, icon: FontAwesomeIcons.thumbtack),
                    _buildButton(45, color: Colors.green, icon:FontAwesomeIcons.sprayCan),
                    _buildButton(90, color: Colors.orange, icon: FontAwesomeIcons.fire),
                    _buildButton(135, color: Colors.blue, icon:FontAwesomeIcons.kiwiBird),
                    _buildButton(180, color: Colors.black, icon:FontAwesomeIcons.cat),
                    _buildButton(225, color: Colors.indigo, icon:FontAwesomeIcons.paw),
                    _buildButton(270, color: Colors.pink, icon: FontAwesomeIcons.bong),
                    _buildButton(315, color: Colors.yellow, icon:FontAwesomeIcons.bolt),
                    Transform.scale(
                      scale: scale.value - 1,
                      child: FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.timesCircle), onPressed: _close, backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                    ),
                    Transform.scale(
                      scale: scale.value,
                      child: FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidDotCircle), onPressed: _open),
                    )

                  ])
          );
        });
  }

  _open() {
    controller.forward();
  }

  _close() {
    controller.reverse();
  }

  _buildButton(double angle, { required Color color, required IconData icon }) {
    final double rad = radians(angle);
    return Transform(
        transform: Matrix4.identity()..translate(
            (translation.value) * cos(rad),
            (translation.value) * sin(rad)
        ),

        child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(icon), backgroundColor: color, onPressed: _close, elevation: 0)
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stack isn't blocking the buttons. Actually, it is not even aware of its children. When you apply the Matrix transformation to the buttons, you push them outside the Stack widget, which prevents them from receiving pointer events.

May not be an ideal workaround depending on your case, but providing the Stack a height and width will fix the issue. The buttons will remain within the boundaries of the Stack even after the transformation:

```dart
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    const SizedBox(height: 250, width: 250), // <== Add this line to the top
    _buildButton(0, color: Colors.red, icon: Icons.clear),
    _buildButton(45, color: Colors.green, icon: Icons.clear),
    _buildButton(90, color: Colors.orange, icon: Icons.clear),
    _buildButton(135, color: Colors.blue, icon: Icons.clear),
    _buildButton(180, color: Colors.black, icon: Icons.clear),
    _buildButton(225, color: Colors.indigo, icon: Icons.clear),
    _buildButton(270, color: Colors.pink, icon: Icons.clear),
    _buildButton(315, color: Colors.yellow, icon: Icons.clear),
    Transform.scale(
      scale: scale.value - 1,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.clear),
          onPressed: _close,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red),
    ),
    Transform.scale(
      scale: scale.value,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.clear), onPressed: _open),
    )
  ],
)
```